# Background audio for one specific activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to add my recorded audio in background of the activity in which I am explaining an example. Problem is that audio do not stop after ending the activity and it keeps on playing. I want audio only to be played when my activity is at front. Kindly put the service class in following code

```
public class exp extends Activity {
    ImageView imview1,imview2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addexample);

        imview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        imview2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: in the above code there is no audio playing logic!

Comment: yes I havent. Please tell where to do

Comment: Paste the sections of code relevant to audio and where you observed _Problem is that audio do not stop after ending the activity_

Comment: start the sound in on create. You can search for a tutorial on how to do so. Then make sure you stop the player in `onpause()` method of `activity`.

Comment: Dont see any audio code.

Comment: in the same class?? @SherAlam

Comment: Yes in the same class. Just google for tutorial. Usually the music stopping code is given in tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

In `onResume` start your audio

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //start your audio track here
    }
```

Stop the same in `onPause`

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        //Sop it over here
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Create the player instances in `onCreate`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class exp extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addexample);

    //player starting code goes here.
 }

 protected void onPause() {
    //stop the music player here.
}
}
```

Comment: is ma service class ko extend krny ki zrrort nae ?? @sher

Comment: No not at all. As long as your activity is visible, your player will be running.

Comment: Now if want to create an audio player (the one that runs in the background) then off course you have to use service in order to play the audio even if your player is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop your audio in onPause:

```
public class exp extends Activity {
ImageView imview1,imview2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addexample);

    imview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    imview2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }, 2000);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    //Kill your audio
}
```

}

I think your solution is something like that. Try it and comment

Good look!